# OpenTK GL.MatrixMode and GL.LoadMatrix not found

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm trying to fix a problem while running into those two stackoverflow questons [OpenGL with OpenTK wrapper cannot get projections to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676300/opengl-with-opentk-wrapper-cannot-get-projections-to-work) and [OpenTK Camera in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689788/opentk-camera-in-c-sharp). Both state I should use GL functions I just don't have!
What am I doing wrong/how can I get those? All three aren't available, even with the following usings

```
GL.MatrixMode()
MatrixMode.Projection
GL.LoadMatrix()

using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using OpenTK;
```

My guess is I missed a using, but since visual studio doesn't show me a single hotfix I'm kind of lost

Comment: Does it work if you add the following: `using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;`?

Comment: It actually does, thank you!! Of course, everything else now is ambiguous, I'll delete the using OpenGl4. Is it bad if I use opengl in this one class but opengl4 everywere else? And how am I supposed to get the functionality of those functions in OpenGL4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find up-to-date documentation for OpenTK, but seems that those `using` statements only import modern OpenGL functionality. As I said in comments, adding `using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;` imports older functions such as those in your question.

Modern OpenGL doesn't have functions for matrices, you must implement the functionality yourself, eg. declaring a matrix as a `float matrix[ 16 ]` and upload the matrices as uniforms using `GL.UniformMatrix4`.

Comment: So I should implement them by myself is what you're saying. That's unfortunate, because I came to those described functions exactly because doing it manually didn't work for me..: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370564/opentk-after-multiplying-with-projectionmatrix-nothing-is-rendering-anymore?noredirect=1#comment77713666_45370564